# CollectionView inside a TableView scrollViewDidEndDecelerating crash

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview, tableview

In `UITableView` (horizontally scrolling) `numberOfRowsInSection` is dynamic number. In `UICollectionView` (vertically scrolling) `numberOfItemsInSection` is also dynamic.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (self.arrayNewsfeedsList[intIndex]as! Newsfeeds).media!.count//3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "sliderCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! sliderCollectionViewCell
    let stringImageUrl = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/CQElIZzzlpc/hqdefault.jpg"
    cell.imageViewSlider.setKRImageUrl(url:stringImageUrl) { (imageUser) in
        cell.imageViewSlider.image = imageUser
    }       
    return cell
}
```

While scrolling `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` and scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation, the app is geting crashed.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let cell = tableviewNewsfeed.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: intIndex) as IndexPath)as! NewsfeedTableViewCell
    cell.pagecontrolYoutube?.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / Int(scrollView.frame.width - 50)
}

func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let cell = tableviewNewsfeed?.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 0 , section: intIndex) as IndexPath)as! NewsfeedTableViewCell
    cell.pagecontrolYoutube?.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / Int(scrollView.frame.width - 50)
}
```

How do I update this line?

```
tableviewNewsfeed?.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: 0 , section: intIndex) as IndexPath)as! NewsfeedTableViewCell
```

See this image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOL1b.jpg

Comment: So what exactly is `nil` at that point? When the compiler stops, please put this in the console: `po tableviewNewsFeed`

Comment: > Link po tableviewNewsFeed: https://imgur.com/a/NmiVqyb

Comment: In cellForRowAt ,I have updating  the Indexpath.section .   intIndex = indexPath.section

Comment: What does this print? `po tableviewNewsfeed.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: intIndex))`

Comment: >output : nil . How to update the Indexpath value while scrolling the tableview ?

Comment: BTW you can just do `IndexPath(row: 0, section: intIndex)` instead of `NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: intIndex) as IndexPath`

Comment: same result .nil is occurring

Comment: I know, just a hint for improving your code :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest to avoid sticking a UITableView inside a UICollectionView - it's always a bad idea with cells reuse and it just going to mess thing up somewhere down the line. Try working with [IGListKit](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit) - it helps to easily manage nested data structures, check out their examples.

As for your code - the way to go about the nested setup - is to have one `UICollecionViewCell` to hold an entire `UITableView` and not try to count the number of table cells and pass this number to UICollectionView delegate method. So - return just 1 cell for collection view section:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

And then manage UITableView setup entirely in a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your table view is not displaying first cell at that time. So IF it is not visible then you always get nil for row 0.

Get current visible row at that time. Then you will get the cell object.

```
tableviewNewsfeed?.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: currentVisibleRow , section: intIndex) as IndexPath)as! NewsfeedTableViewCell
```

Comment: okay fine . what is currentVisibleRow in code and how to get for tableview ?

Comment: Table view cell working as a page for page control? then you can calculate it as per current page you are already calculating . or tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
This will give you all visible indexpaths